# Does QGIS have an autocomplete polygon option like the one in ArcGIS?

Tags: qgis, polygon, editing, topology

I am trying to do digitizing in QGIS, but I do not see an option that I have seen in ArcGIS - autocomplete polygon. I would like to make two adjacent polygons topologically correct, and can not find such an option in QGIS.

Comment: You might indicate what version of QGIS you are using.  There is this thread: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/12331/is-there-any-auto-complete-polygon-tool-in-qgis, but in my version of 2.14 there is no Avoid Intersections box.  However, you might try checking Settings - Snapping Options - Enable Topological Editing and see if that works.

Answer (score 5):

You must open "Snapping options" under settings and mark the layer that you want to draw and "adjacent polygon". Then mark "Avoid Intersection".